# Can I get the Lotus to stop repeating herself?

Tags: warframe

I know the Lotus says a lot of the same things in the various mission types. And it was helpful when I started playing, but honestly, I know the mission types, the flavour text as it were isn't very interesting.

Is there any way I can get her to stop repeating this stuff for every single mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the Lotus's instructions can be disabled by heading to `esc->options->audio` and unchecking "Enable Hint Transmissions."  It is unclear exactly how much of the Lotus this mutes, but it should help.

Comment: It doesn't appear to mute everything but it mutes some of it, which I appreciate!